# Chrome Lighthouse comma and full stop in performance option

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a few questions regarding the report of [lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) (see screenshot below)

1. The first [is a culture think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark): i assume the value `11.930 ms` stands for 11 seconds and 930 ms. Is this the case?
2. The second is the Delayed Paint compared to the size. The third entry (7.22 KB) delays the paint by `3,101 ms` the fourth entry delays the paint by `1,226  ms` although the javascript file is more than three times  the size `24.03 KB` versus `7.22 KB`. Does anybody know what might be the cause?

### Screenshot of Lighthouse

This is an extract of a lighthouse report. In the screenshot of [google-chrome-lighthouse](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-lighthouse) you can see that a few metrics are written with a comma `11,222 ms` and others with a full stop `7.410 ms`

[image: google chrome lighthouse screenshot]

Comment: Does the culture setting on your computer specify a dot for thousands separator? Anyway, this is definitely confusing and seems like a bug worth fixing - all timings should use the same format e.g. 1,234.567 ms (I'd drop the decimal precision though, 1ms is sufficient for granularity).

Comment: My os is running in german (dot is a thousand seperator). My chrome beta is in german (setting it to english seems to be deactivated).

Comment: Yeah, definitely a bug then: half the numbers (look at the sizes) displayed use dot for fractional part.

Comment: It's terrible, actually. See if it's reported in the github repo and add an issue otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for discovering quite a bug! An [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/3115) has been filed in the Lighthouse GitHub repo.

To explain what's likely going on, it looks like this report was generated with the CLI (or at least a locale that is different from the one that it is being displayed in). Some numbers (such as the ones in the table) are converted to strings ahead of time while others are converted at display time in the browser. The browser numbers are respecting your OS/user-selected locale while the pre-stringified numbers are not.

To answer your questions...

1. Yes, the value it's reporting is 11930 milliseconds or 11 seconds and 930 milliseconds (11,930 ms en-US or 11.930 ms de-DE).
2. The delayed paint metric is reporting to you how many milliseconds after the load started the asset finished loading. There are multiple factors that influence this number including when the asset was discovered by the browser, queuing time, server response time, network variability, and payload size. The small script that delayed paint longer likely had a lower priority or was added to your page later than the larger script was and thus was pushed out farther.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; glad i could help.